# Java generic List parameter not possible?

Tags: java, generics

i have a simple method that takes a generic List parameter but for some reason my IDE(Eclipse) states how it cannot be resolved?

Am i doing something wrong here

```
private OnClickListener removeFieldListener(final LinearLayout layout,
            List<T> viewList) {

        return new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int indexToDelete = layout.indexOfChild(v);

            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: I'll just add to Riduidel's answer, that it seems the generic parameter is not needed in this case, unless the OnClickListener is intended to use T as well. I.e., private <T> OnClickListener<T> removeFieldListener ...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In that case, the T parameter has to be defined somewhere. As I guess your class does not declares this parameter, you have to put it in your method declaration, like

```
private <T> OnClickListener removeFieldListener(final LinearLayout layout,
        List<T> viewList) {
```

But this will only move the problem to the caller of this method ...

Comment: Actually, this shouldn't move the problem to callers - Java will use type inference to work out what the `T` is based on the type of the list being passed in.  So there shouldn't be any additional burden on callers, compared to using a wildcard or the raw type.

Comment: ahh ok, how would i define this generic T in the class? i know i could do something like public class hello<T> but if i do that, the caller of this whole class would need to specify this generic type which i dont want to do as the method above is a private method and deals with private variables that are dealt from within this class not the caller of this class. im guessing i can do something along the declaration of this class with something like private Generic T; ?

Comment: @jonney - see in Riduidel's example, the `<T>` that's the second part of the signature.  This means that the *method* is parameterised without you needing to add a generic parameter to the class.  See the [Generic Methods section of the generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedMethods.html#Fundamentals).

Comment: Yup i got it. thanks. so in a nutshell, generics can be defined in the class definition or in a method definition. sweet. you learn something new every day. cheers to all

Comment: Can I identify the T belongs to which class instance inside the method ?

Answer (score 15):

Riduidel is right in that the problem is that you haven't declared the `T` anywhere.

Depending on what you want to do with the contents of the list, chances are you can just use a wildcard.  `List<?> viewList` would work if you're only pulling `Object`s out of it; or `List<? extends IListener>` will allow you to get IListeners out of it, etc.

In general, you don't need a generic parameter if it only appears once within your method, and you should use a wildcard instead.  If it *does* appear multiple times, for example you remove things from the list and assign them to variables of type `T`, then you do indeed need the wildcard and you should parameterise your method [as Riduidel suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163826/java-generic-list-parameter-not-possible/4163866#4163866).